# Pass output of tmux command into later pane command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, tmux

I'm trying to set up a keybind to toggle a `top` pane in the active window. The way I would like to do this is to:

1. Check to see if a pane started with the `top` command exists in the current window
2. If no such pane exists, `splitw -h top`
3. If such a pane does exist, `killp -t PANE_ID`

I'm able to do the first two parts, under the assumption that I only have a single pane started with the `top` command using the following shell commands in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
topid="tmux lsp -f '#{==:#{pane_start_command},top}' -F '#D'"
hastop="$topid | grep '%' -q"
```

So the first shell command finds all panes which were started with `top` and prints their pane ID. The second essentially just `grep`s for a `%` symbol and I assume I'll either have a single match or no matches, in which case `$?` will correctly infer whether a pane exists.

I can (in theory, anyway) use `if-shell "$hastop"` to detect whether the current window has a `top` pane, or at least the commands work if I operate directly in the shell.

The problem is that I want to store the result of `topid` in a variable so I can pass it to `killp -t ID_HERE`, and I'm not sure how to persist that string so I can pass (interpolate?) it into my `killp` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `if-shell` use `run-shell` and code the logic inside a *single piece* of shell code where you can work with shell variables freely.

The following example is a command to run in a shell inside tmux. It binds to <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> (note it's *capital* T). If you want to put the command into your `.tmux.conf` then omit the leading `tmux` .

```
tmux bind-key T run-shell '
pane="$(
   tmux list-panes -f "#""{==:#""{pane_start_command},top}" -F "#""D" | head -n 1
)"
[ -n "$pane" ] && tmux kill-pane -t "$pane" || tmux split-window -bf top
'
```

The logic is: if `$pane` expands to a non-empty string then `kill-pane`. Otherwise (or if `kill-pane` fails) perform `split-window`.

These double double-quotes after each `#` are important. We don't want `run-shell` to see and expand `#{` or `#D`, we want `list-panes` to see them. Upon the keystroke `run-shell` will parse the whole single-quoted string, including double-quotes, so it will see "meaningless" `#""{` and `#""D`. Then a shell run by `run-shell` will remove double-quotes and thus `list-panes` will see meaningful `#{` and `#D`.

I used `split-window -bf top` to make `top` start on top. :) Adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, this works swimmingly. I guess my follow-on question boils down to deducing when I should defer to just running normal shell commands versus trying to handle everything procedurally within my `.tmux.conf`. It just seems like there should be a way to feed the output from one tmux command to a following command without needing to resort to the shell, since what we really need the shell for here is to populate `pane`.